# Classes and constructor in Es6 program

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-class

Create a class car with a constructor function which accepts 2 parameters (name and distance). Include a prototype method in class, which returns a message(msg) "car name(name) had travelled for distance(distance) miles".

I know its a very simple question, but I guess I am not able to design the code well, though it is giving me the right result yet I believe as per standards it is not right??

```js
class Car {
  constructor(name, distance) {
    this.name = name;
    this.distance = distance;

  }
  lengthMiles() {
    console.log(`${this.name} had travelled for ${this.distance} miles`)
  }
}

var msg = new Car('Audi', 100);
msg.lengthMiles();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class Car {
  constructor(name, distance) {
    this.name = name;
    this.distance = distance;

  }
  carDistance() {
    return `${this.name} had travelled for ${this.distance} miles`;
  }
}
let Car1 = new Car('Audi', 100);
const msg = Car1.carDistance();
console.log(msg);
module.exports = {msg}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem statement reads:

> Include a prototype method in class, which **returns a message**(msg) "car name(name) had travelled for distance(distance) miles".

Which should mean that the method actually uses `return` instead of printing to the console.

```js
class Car {
  constructor(name, distance) {
    this.name = name;
    this.distance = distance;

  }
  lengthMiles() {
    return `${this.name} had travelled for ${this.distance} miles`;
//  ^^^^^^ --------------------------- using a return statement
  }                            //    |
}                              //    |
                               //    |
var car = new Car('Audi', 100);//    |
var msg = car.lengthMiles();   //    |
console.log(msg);// <----------------- printing the message here
```

Comment: Thanks I will check this one

Comment: Also, quick question, when we talk about using a prototype ; it is basically a non -constructor function/ method.

Comment: Yes, all methods defined inside `class` are actually attached to the prototype. That part of the question honestly sounds weird because if you have a class, you should just say "include a method", no need to mention the prototype.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs though. Really appreciate it!!

Comment: Surprisigly, though the code runs; it is still giving the npm error. The snippet is below:
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

audited 6063 packages in 5.759s

found 232 high severity vulnerabilities

  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

> class@1.0.0 test /projects/challenge

> mocha test --reporter mocha-junit-reporter

Car Audi had travelled for distance 1000 miles

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

Answer (score -1):

```
     class Car {
      constructor(name, distance) {
        this.name = name;
        this.distance = distance;
      }
      carDistance() {
        return `${this.name} had travelled for ${this.distance} miles`;
      }
     }
     let Car1 = new Car('Audi', 100);
     const msg = Car1.carDistance();
     console.log(msg);
     module.exports = {msg}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.